# How can I format '07/03/2018' to 'March 7th 2018' in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, date-formatting

I need to show the date format as `March 7th 2018` in `crystal reports`. I tried this using Format editor in crystal report It gives as `March 07 2018` but not as I wanted. How to do this formatting?

Comment: The trickiest part is the `th`, there's no in built Crystal function for this, it needs to be handled by a custom function. Is this part necessary?

Comment: @bendataclear Yes  ,Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, there's no builtin function in Crystal Reports to format the day as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th...

With the following formula you will get the desired result:

```
Select Day({@myDate})
    Case 1, 21, 31:
        ToText({@myDate}, "MMMM d'st' yyyy")
    Case 2, 22:
        ToText({@myDate}, "MMMM d'nd' yyyy")
    Case 3, 23:
        ToText({@myDate}, "MMMM d'rd' yyyy")
    Default:
        ToText({@myDate}, "MMMM d'th' yyyy")
```

**Note:** The month-name will be displayed depending on the locale-settings of your system.